# @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Tags: spring-boot

Here is my code github link: https://github.com/448267450/pop-movies.
This is a java spring boot project.
When I ran the project under the file of MovieApplication.Java,an error occurred:

> ---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Field movieRepository in dev.wenkun.movies.MovieService required a bean of type 'dev.wenkun.movies.MovieRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
- @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'dev.wenkun.movies.MovieRepository' in your configuration.

wenkun@WenkundeMacBook-Pro movies %

> 

I double checked service and repository file, but seemed nothing was wrong.
Anyone can help me pls?

I double checked service and repository file, but seemed nothing was wrong.
Anyone can help me pls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can resolve just by change this dependency.

**AS-IS**

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

**TO-BE**

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```